# Android navigating between multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I'm new to android app building, i'm doing this as an requirement for my college project. Please assist me.

My app has swiping tabs, using fragment. I have 5 tabs and 5 Fragments, In some tabs (fragments) i need to navigate to new fragments within the fragments; e.g. when in Tab1 i have buttons when pressed will bring user to new fragment, I had searched the internet and managed to write the code. My issue is when in Tab1 and press button to go to new fragment i'm getting " app stopped working" please assist me

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

 public class Unsafe extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unsafe, container, false);
    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.u1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),unsafe1.class));
}
}
```

UPDATE - Posting Logcat

```
12-03 08:59:39.538    1460-1460/com.example.hfacs D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-03 08:59:39.538    1460-1460/com.example.hfacs W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a77b90)
12-03 08:59:39.538      379-645/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.example.hfacs/.Unsafe1} from pid 1460
12-03 08:59:39.588    1460-1460/com.example.hfacs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hfacs, PID: 1460
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.hfacs/com.example.hfacs.Unsafe1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3423)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3384)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
            at com.example.hfacs.Unsafe$1.onClick(Unsafe.java:28)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use fragmentpageadapter..

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to always post the logcat along with your question. especially when it's about an error.

Comment: @kdehairy sorry about that, i had posted logcat. please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not call startActivity() in onClick.
Instead, when user click on the button, notify the FragmentActivity containing this fragment. Inside the FragmentActivity, call ViewPager.setCurrentItem(position), where position is an int. The view pager will then scroll to the desired tab.

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it. But I tried this before and it works.
Add a function in your FragmentActivity, which is used to scroll to the desired tab.

```
public static void scroll(int pos){
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos); //mViewPager is the ViewPager you have in FragmentActivity
}
```

And this is the onClickListener

```
Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.u1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //when button clicked, call the scroll function
            MainActivity.scroll(position_of_unsafe1);   //MainActivity is the FragmentActivity name         
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information - can you please elaborate on how to achieve this.

Comment: @user3061569 I have added some code. I hope it is what you want to achieve. Here, I am assuming that unsafe1 is one of the fragments in one of the tabs.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the assistance, Unsafe1 is not one of the fragments in one of the tabs. Unsafe1 is a content within a particular tab. If i can say it is " tab within a tab ". kindly assist me.

Comment: @user3061569 This is the format of the manifest file of one of my app.
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Unsafe1" />
<activity android:name=".unsafeT" />

Comment: Hi, Thank you, this is my manifest file [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ckYP7ht1p9M0hhSk5YbHZRMDg/edit?usp=sharing) please let me know if there is discrepancies. I still get same error.

Comment: @user3061569 Try to remove the line  <action android:name=".Unsafe1" />    
Instead, add a line <activity android:name=".Unsafe1"/>   in between </activity>  and  </application> , which are the 3rd last and 2nd last line in your manifest file.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting ' java.lang.NullPointerException ' now

Answer (score 0):

I spotted this line in the logcat:

```
ndroid.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.hfacs/com.example.hfacs.Unsafe1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

That means you did not declare the activity `Unsafe1` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I notice that too. But when i add the ' Unsafe1 ' in manifest.xml and run the app, it only runs Unsafe1.Java . below is my AndroidManifest.xml   <activity
            android:name="com.example.hfacs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

Comment: what do you mean by "it only runs Unsafe1.java"? isn't that the activity you want to run, judging by the `startActivity(...)` line in your code?

Comment: Hi, i'm running Mainactivity and unsafe1 is a class. please refer here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ckYP7ht1p9a0lOaUZBbkRxYjg/edit?usp=sharing)